# Apple Maps and Google Maps API feasibility

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, apple-maps

I want to build an application where the user can see his current location, and all the users logged in to the app as well.

I want to build it for Android and IOS.
Can I use Apple Maps on IOS and Google Maps API on Android?

Will the application be able to show the current logged in users location on both IOS and Android with no problems? even though am using Apple maps on IOS and Google Maps API on Android?

To be more clear: the android user can also see the IOS users on the map and Vice-Versa

Or I have to use Google Maps API on IOS as well?

Comment: Just start doing and you will figure it out. Both map takes lat/lng feed for map so you can use any map and feed any valid lat/lng to populate the map regardless of what device the user is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible. Just you need to save the lat long on your server of every logged in user. And while any client i.e. Android or iOS app login the app you can have an endpoint that returns the location of all logged in users in server. For server component, you need to develop one endpoint to save the lat long and one endpoint to fetch all the lat long's saved on server.

Answer (score 1):

Of course can. iOS and Android native components will return you same location (as much as possible apart) in [spherical coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system%22Spherical%20coordinate%20system%22), then you can do with this location what do you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. The information is sent by the clients, on the server side you can manage/handle that information as you want/need ;)